# Conditionally join two words stored in an array returned by XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If `XLOOKUP` returns an array (stored in a variable called `x` by `LET` function) spanning two columns, I have three cases:

1- Both columns are empty by having an empty value of `""`

2- First column has a six character word, while the second column has an empty value of `""`

3- Each column has a six character word.

I need to return empty value `""` in the first case, only the first column word in the second case, and both words joined by a line break in the third case.

Is is possible to test only the second element in the array `x` if it is ="" or not?

P.S. `TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,XLOOKUP(...))` doesn't work nor `IFS( SUM(LEN(x)) = 6, x, SUM(LEN(x)) > 6, textjoin() )`

Comment: use `TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,XLOOKUP(...))`

Comment: @ScottCraner It breaks the line even though the second returned value in the array is `""`.

Comment: Then it is not returning a true empty string.  Make sure there is no space or other non printable character.

Comment: I don't know why it considers `""` something and breaks the line.

Comment: You need to show more details.  Give us some examples of your data, how your data is created and the xlookup formula you are using.  Somewhere in that you are capturing something that looks blank but is not.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is it possible to test only the second element in the array `x` if it is `=""` or not?

Comment: What does len() give?

Comment: @SolarMike 0, 6, 12, respectively.

Comment: Sure, `=INDEX(xlookup(...),2)=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple answer using

```
TEXTJOIN( CHAR(10),,FILTER(x, x <> ""))
```

However, I don't understand why `""` is not discarded by the option `ignore empty` in `textjoin`.